# Select Column from tableview

Tags: java, javafx

```
TableColumn<ManagePermitsView, String> mngtpvpermitColumn = new TableColumn<>("Permit");

mngtpvpermitColumn.setMinWidth(150);
mngtpvpermitColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("VPPermit"));
TableColumn<ManagePermitsView, String> mngtpvvalidColumn = new TableColumn<>("Validity");
mngtpvvalidColumn.setMinWidth(150);
mngtpvvalidColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("VPValid"));
TableColumn<ManagePermitsView, String> mngtpvdocumentColumn = new TableColumn<>("Document");
mngtpvdocumentColumn.setMinWidth(150);
mngtpvdocumentColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("VPDocument"));

TableView mngtvptable = new TableView<>();
mngtvptable.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
mngtvptable.getColumns().addAll(mngtpvpermitColumn, mngtpvvalidColumn, mngtpvdocumentColumn);
mngtvptable.setItems(getManagePermitsView(mngtvregnumSelected));


topmenu.getChildren().clear();
topmenu.getChildren().addAll(mngtvvpdpermitbtn, mngtvedpermitbtn, mngtvdepermitbtn, mngtvgbackbtn);
middlebox.getChildren().clear();
middlebox.getChildren().addAll(mngtvptable);

mngtvedpermitbtn.setOnAction(mngtvedpb->{
    String mngtpvprSelected = mngtvptable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getVPPermit();

});
```

I am getting error in `String mngtpvprSelected = mngtvptable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getVPPermit();`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use raw types. (Surely your IDE is giving you a warning about this???)

Specifically, replace

```
TableView mngtvptable = new TableView<>();
```

with

```
TableView<ManagePermitsView> mngtvptable = new TableView<>();
```

I assume `ManagePermitsView` has a `getVPPermit()` method returning a `String`.